# What is meant by a meet-in-the-middle approach?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory, cryptography, software

I'm studing C. Petit's work "Faster algorithms for isogeny problems using torsion point images" ([link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/571.pdf)) and he talks about meet-in-the-middle approach/strategy for solve some isogenies problems.

Well, what does Petit mean with meet-in-the-middle approach/strategy?

I've read that it's an approach that allows you to reduce the complexity of a problem with the aim of using brute force to solve it, but what does it mean in mathematical language?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "meet in the middle approach", also known as "bidirectional search", is a method to find shortest paths in graphs. It was proposed by Pohl [1] and first used by Galbraith [2] to construct isogenies between elliptic curves $E$ and $E'$. One builds two trees of isogenies from both sides of $E$ and $E'$, and finds a collision between the two trees to obtain the shortest path from $E$ to $E'$.

[1] [Bi-directional and heuristic search in path problems](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Bi-directional-and-heuristic-search-in-path-Pohl/e609ab97186834bd97d3fbc0c97a19744d752c23), I Pohl (1969).
[2] [Constructing isogenies between elliptic curves over finite fields](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/iso.pdf), S.D. Galbraith (2011).

Comment: NB it's not obvious that this is an improvement: 
instead of searching the $N^2$ leaves of a single tree, 
we seek a coincidence between the $N+N$ leaves of two trees, 
which might still seem to take time $N^2$ to find.  
The key is that sorting can be done in time $O(N \log N)$,
and once each tree's leaves are sorted we can find a match in time only $O(N)$.
Likewise for other applications of this trick.  
Note that this requires on the order of $N$ *space*;
sometimes there are refinements that reduce the space cost
while keeping the $O(N \log N)$ timing.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, if the structure can be hashed then it might be possible to eliminate the sort and get to $O(N)$ time.